# Como faço para ler um XML com marcação HTML

Tags: php, html, xml

Tenho um XML onde dentro dele tem uma table completa. Como eu faço para ler esse XML e já imprimir essa estrutura da Table em html?

Estou trabalhando em PHP

XML

```
<document page-count="1">
    <page number="1">
        <table data-filename="p01.pdf" data-page="1" data-table="1">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="6">FULANO DE TAL</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </page>
</document>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você já está usando alguma biblioteca do PHP? Senão, tente usar a [SimpleXML](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.simplexml.php).

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('arq.xml');

    foreach ($xml->children() as $page){

        foreach($page->children() as $table){
            echo "<table";

            foreach($table->attributes() as $att => $valor){
                echo " $att='$valor'";
            }

            echo " style='border: 1px solid black'>";

            foreach($table->children() as $tr){

                echo "<tr>";

                foreach($tr->children() as $td){
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $td;
                    echo "</td>";
                }

                echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";
        }

        echo "<br>Página ". $page["number"];
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Irá imprimir:

```html
<table data-filename='p01.pdf' data-page='1' data-table='1' style='border: 1px solid black'>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>FULANO DE TAL</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
Página 1
<br>
```

Comment: Você pode trocar o ```echo "<table"``` que inicia o elemento HTML para ```"<". $table->getName()```, por exemplo. Assim ele sempre acompanha os elementos que estão no XML

Answer (score 4):

Usar uma séries de `foreach` para algo assim é dar uma volta imensa em algo que pode ser resolvido de forma simples, se usar `DOMDocument::saveHTML` combinado com `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`

Exemplo mais eficiente e sem necessidade de loops:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('arq.xml');

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

if ($tables->length) {
    $table = $tables->item(0);//Pega a primeira tabela
    echo $dom->saveHTML($table); //Exibe o conteudo da tabela
} else {
    echo 'Tabela não encontrada';
}
```

Exemplo online para teste: https://repl.it/@inphinit/innerhtml-outerhtml-in-php

Documentação para funções úteis para manipular DOM com PHP:

- carregar um arquivo ou stream XML: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php
- carregar um string em formato XML: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php
- carregar um string em **formato HTML**: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php
- carregar um string em **formato HTML**: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php
- Pegar **um elemento** pelo ID: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php
- Pegar um ou mais elementos (`DOMNodeList`) pelo nome da tag: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php
- Pegar um ou mais elementos (`DOMNodeList`) pelo nome da tag que use namespace do documento: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php
- Retorna o conteudo DOM como uma string em formato XML: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php
- Retorna o conteudo DOM como uma string em formato HTML: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php