# Exibir dados de array

Tags: php, array, xml

Preciso exibir os dados desse `array` e não estou sabendo fazer a chamada.
Gostaria de pegar dados específicos como `[Postage] => 140.55`

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (

                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 12
                            )

                        [Pounds] => 2
                        [Ounces] => 0
                        [Machinable] => True
                        [MailType] => Package
                        [Container] => RECTANGULAR
                        [Size] => REGULAR
                        [Width] => 2
                        [Length] => 2
                        [Height] => 2
                        [Girth] => 0
                        [Country] => BRAZIL
                        [Postage] => 140.55
                        [ExtraServices] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [ExtraService] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [ServiceID] => 106
                                        [ServiceName] => Insurance
                                        [Available] => True
                                        [Price] => 1.00
                                        [DeclaredValueRequired] => True
                                    )

                            )

                        [ValueOfContents] => 200.00
                        [SvcCommitments] => 1 - 3 business days to many major markets
                        [SvcDescription] => USPS GXG<sup>™</sup> Envelopes
                        [MaxDimensions] => USPS-Produced regular size cardboard envelope (12-1/2" x 9-1/2"), the legal-sized cardboard envelope (15" x 9-1/2") and the GXG Tyvek envelope (15-1/2" x 12-1/2")
                        [MaxWeight] => 70
                    )
```

Comment: ```$var->Postage``` não resolve?

Comment: Acabei de responder uma pergunta parecida com a sua https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/334455/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-ler-um-xml-com-marca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-html/334544#334544

Comment: $var->Postage não resolve, já tentei, na verdade a estrutura é maior que isso. É um retorno de uma consulta em uma api dos correios dos USA. mas fica muito grande pra mandar aqui.

Comment: Tenta assim: $v[0]->Postage

Answer (score -1):

Basta você acessar a posição zero do array e o atributo.

$var[0]->Postage;